# Problems with autolayout when using "equals width"?

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I have almost a usual situation:
[image]

The difference is the first stripe has height constraint:

```
height = some_constant * parentView.height
```

And in the same time standard keyboard can appear and so I need to compress all the items. The app should decrease the distance between the views. If it is not enough then the first view may have negative top constraint.

Could you explain how to solve this issue

Comment: You can have spacer of same height in between elements and set the height of the spacer with respect to the parent view, so that if the height increases spacer's height increases with it too and this will give you desired result, and when the keyboard appears, you reduce the height spacer, it will squeeze.

Comment: Have you tried a `UIStackView`? You should achieve the negative offset on top by setting the top offset to a low priority. Lower than height compression resistance of the stack view.

Comment: @iphonic, interesting idea, i'll try it.

Comment: @macmoonshine, NO. The problem is it is supported in ios 9+ but I need also ios8.